# $\iint_D f = 0$ implies $f(p)=0$ for all $p$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $D$ is open, and if $f$ is continuous, bounded, and obeys $f(p) \ge 0$ for all $p \in D$, then $\iint_D f = 0$ implies $f(p)=0$ for all $p$.

The hint in the back of my book says that

> There's a neighborhood where $f(p) \ge \delta$.

From the definition in my book, it states that

> The double integral $\iint_R f$ exists and has value $v$ if and only if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
>
> $|S(N,f,\{p_{ij}\})-v| < \delta$.

There's another theorem in the book that states that

> If $f(p) \ge 0$ for all $p\in D$, $\iint_D f \ge 0$.

So far, from the information I've been given, that would mean that I could use the contrapositive to prove that if $f(p) \ne 0$ for all $p$, then $\iint_D f \ne 0$.

Since $f(p) \ne 0$ I could use cases.

Case 1: If $f(p) > 0$, then I could use the aforementioned theorem to show that $\iint_D f > 0$ which is not equal to $0$.

Case 2: If $f(p) < 0$, then $-f(p)=g(p)>0$, so that $\iint_D g(p) > 0$. Then $\iint_D g(p) > 0$ is equivalent to -$\iint_D f(p) > 0$ which is not equal to $0$.

I would like to know if I'm approaching this proof the correct way? Also, would it be difficult to instead try a direct proof using the hint and the definition that I stated above?

Comment: There is sort of a way to attack this if you break $D$ into two sets: places where $f(p)  \geq \delta$ and places where it's not.

Comment: So that integral is improper?  Do your theorems in the text permit that?

Comment: The integral is defined on $D$. Also, the theorem stated above requires that $D$ is bounded. Although, the definition says that the double integral exists for the conditions listed above for $R$, which the book states is a rectangle, so I think that that means that the integral must be bounded.

Comment: @SeanRoberson: is the $\delta$ referring to the $\delta$ used in $|S(N,f,\{p_{ij}\})| < \delta$?

Comment: You do not need Case 2 as $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in D$.

Comment: I just thought about that, and that's true I don't need it

Comment: It is not clear how you are going "to use the aforementioned theorem to show" what you need. Could you explain it?

Comment: I was thinking that I could show that if $f(p)>0$, then $\iint_D f >0$ to prove the contrapositve. But I don't think that I could do that since the theorem states that if $f(p) \ge 0$ then $\iint_D f \ge 0$ which is different from the contrapositive, "f $f(p) \ne 0$, then $\iint_D f  \ne 0$". So, at this point I don't really know how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using the hint from your book, assume, toward a contradiction, that $f(p)=r >0$ for some $p\in D$. Then continuity of $f$ at $p$ implies that there is a square $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ containing $p$ such that $f(x)>r/2$ whenever $x\in [a,b]\times [c,d].$ (Drawing a picture and picking a suitable $\epsilon$ for the standard $\epsilon-\delta$ argument will help here).

But then, using an elementary property of the Riemann integral, we can write

$\int_D f\ge \int_{[a,b]\times [c,d]}f>\frac{r}{2}(b-a)(d-c)>0$ and we have our contradiction.

Comment: I was wondering if you meant that $f(p) = r < 0$ for some $p \in D$ and that continuity of $f$ at $p$ implies that there is a square containing '$p$ such that $f(x) < r/2$? Also, should the square be an open set?

Comment: You know $f\ge0$ and you want to prove it is never strictly positive; so you are assuming it is positive somewhere, and getting a contradiction. The original square you get using a $\delta-\epsilon$ argument will be an open set, but you can then always get a  CLOSED square inside it, so  the conclusion still holds on the closed square. That's why I said to draw a picture!

Comment: Using $r = f(p_0)$, I can set $\epsilon = \frac{r}{2}$ and so I see that by definition of continuity of $f$, we have that $|f(x)-f(p)|< \epsilon$ whenever $x \in [a,b]$ x $[c,b]$ implies that $-\epsilon< f(x) - f(p) < \epsilon$, so that $f(x)>f(p)-\epsilon = r - \frac{r}{2} = \frac{r}{2}$. Although, I would like to know as an aside if you could possibly explain how I could incorporate $\delta$ into an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument?

Comment: You almost have it: set $p=(p_1,p_2)$. With your choice of $\epsilon$ you can find a $\delta>0$ (the actual value is not important) such that $x\in (p_1-\sqrt {\delta},p_1+\sqrt {\delta}\times(p_2-\sqrt {\delta},p_2+\sqrt {\delta})\Rightarrow f(x)\in (f(p)-\epsilon,f(p)-\epsilon)$. To conclude, take any closed rectangle inside $ (p_1-\sqrt {\delta},p_1+\sqrt {\delta}\times(p_2-\sqrt {\delta},p_2+\sqrt {\delta})$ and follow the proof I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Extended hint.

Assume $\exists p\in D$ such that $f(p)>0$. To prove $\iint_D f>0$ follow the steps:

1. Prove that there exists a neighborhood $N$ where $f(x)\ge\delta=\frac{f(p)}{2}$. One can even choose $N$ as a disc around $p$.
2. Estimate $\iint_N f\ge\ ?$.
3. Compare $\iint_D f=\iint_N f+\iint_{D\setminus N}f$ and $\iint_N f$.

Comment: For the first part, since $f$ is continuous, and we've assumed that $f(p)>0$, does that mean that it would be better to set $\epsilon = \frac{f(p)}{2}$, so that we can choose a $\delta$ about $p$, simply by convention?

Comment: @K.M No problem to call it $\epsilon$, name does not really matter. I just followed the notation in the book hint that $f(x)\ge\delta$.